# Getting image from pokeapi

Tags: javascript, html, image, display, pokeapi

I am trying to display the image from pokeapi but I get an error when I input the name. When I input the number I do get the pokemon image after clicking twice. But when I search for another pokemon I get a number of the previous pokemon. I would appreciate the help on the proper way to display the image. Thanks.

Javascript:

[image: JS file]

HTML:

[image: html file]

Display image:

[image: display image]

I tried a few ways but cant seem to get it to work.

Comment: Please always supply code as text, not images, as it is generally easier to read and work with.

Answer (score 0):

PokeAPI expects the input to be the name or ID of the Pokemon,try this code please

```
const pokemonInput = document.getElementById("pokemon-input");
const pokemonButton = document.getElementById("pokemon-button");
const pokemonImage = document.getElementById("pokemon-image");

pokemonButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const pokemonName = pokemonInput.value.toLowerCase();
  const apiUrl = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonName}/`;

  fetch(apiUrl)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      const imageUrl = data.sprites.front_default;
      pokemonImage.setAttribute("src", imageUrl);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
      pokemonImage.setAttribute("src", "");
    });
});
```